# What connection string properties I need to use existing database from App_Data folder?

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm practicing for ASP.NET MVC so I downloaded a project from Codeplex for practice. In project there is already existing database files to use in project, I tried to copy and paste the database file in `App_Data` folder, and then I used this connection string

```
<connectionStrings>  
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities"  
         connectionString="Data Source=~/App_Data/MvcMusicStore.mdf"  
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>  
  </connectionStrings>
```

While the database format I have is `.mdf` they have mentioned it `.sdf`, When I try to run the code it through the exception that connection string is not correct.

The database is using a model class named `SampleData`. Another thing is that in project they have provided database of SQL Server CE which used in connection string as

```
providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
```

Comment: `.sdf` = SQL Server **CE** (Compact Edition), while `.mdf` = full-blown **SQL Server** (Express, Web, Standard, Enterprise) - those are **NOT** compatible - you need to use the **correct** tool / data access technology for each

Answer (score 0):

Need more for your Database name.

You can try:

```
<add name="MusicStoreEntities" connectionString="AttachDbFilename=~/App_Data/MvcMusicStore.mdf;Initial Catalog={Your Database Name};Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```